# How to simplify this logical expression in a single return statement?

Tags: c++, logic

I have been trying to simplify this function in a single `return A ... B ... C` statement but some cases always slip out. How could this checks be expressed in a logical way (with `and`, `or`, `not`, etc.)?

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A)
    return true;

if (B)
    return false;
   
if (C)
    return true;

return false;
}
```

Comment: This looks complicated enough that the explicit sequence you provide is most likely easier to understand than a one-liner.

Comment: A way to obtain simple expressions with a systematic procedure is [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). These maps were intensively used in the past (e.g. 40 years ago), for digital board design, before PC and adequate softwares were available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A)
    return true;

if (B)
    return false;
   
if (C)
    return true;

return false;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A)
    return true;
else if (B)
    return false;
else if (C)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A)
    return true;
else if (!B)
{
    if (C)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
else
    return false;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A)
    return true;
else if (!B and C)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A or (!B and C))
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
return (A or (!B and C));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write out all the combinations, you arrive at a table

[image]

```
static std::vector<bool> table{false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true};
```

which you can then extract the value with

```
table[4 * A + 2 * B + C]
```

Taking this one step further, you could simplify to

```
242 & (A << 4 + B << 2 + C)
```

Both are branchless, which is nice.

Comment: "simplify" ? :P

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Occasionally my Z80 machine code days bubble up inside me. I wonder if any compiler optimises to my last expression?

Comment: and now you even managed to get your excel fetish into the answer :P Sadly you already had my vote before

Answer (score 1):

Make a truth table

```
  A    B     C     return
  1    0     0     1
  1    0     1     1
  1    1     0     1
  1    1     1     1
  0    0     0     0
  0    0     1     1
  0    1     0     0
  0    1     1     0
```

Then either you already see how it can be shortened or you just try something, for example:

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
    return A || (C && not B);
}
```

Then write a test to see that it always returns the same. I wrote a "manual" test to see that the same truth table is produced:

```
void test(bool A, bool B, bool C){
    std::cout << A << " " << B << " " << C << " " << f(C,B,A) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  for (int A = 1; A >= 0; --A){
      for (int B = 0; B<2;++B){
          for (int C = 0; C<2;++C){
              test(A,B,C);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

And indeed the [output is](https://godbolt.org/z/cjGh58hed):

```
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
```

TL;DR: When refactoring code tests are of major importance. Write the test make sure it passes, then refactor in tiny steps and make sure that each tiny refactoring still passed the test.

PS: Less code is not always simpler. Depending on what the conditions actually are (and I hope in your real code they have better names than just `A`, `B` and `C`) your original code is potentially much better at expressing the intent of the code than something that uses less lines.

Comment: Your starting the table with 1, 0, 0 is nearly as obfuscated as my 242. Still, +!!242.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

```
bool f(bool C, bool B, bool A)
{
if (A)
    return true;

if (B)
    return false;
   
if (C)
    return true;

return false;
}
```

You can create a boolean matrix for this:

| A | B | C | f(C, B, A) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f | f | f | f |
| f | f | t | t |
| f | t | f | f |
| f | t | t | f |
| t | f | f | t |
| t | f | t | t |
| t | t | f | t |
| t | t | t | t |

The lower half evaluates to `if(A)`
The remainding entries are these:

| B | C | f(C, B, A) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f | f | f |
| f | t | t |
| t | f | f |
| t | t | f |

There is only one true-case here: `if(!B && C)`

To combine these two statements you have to use `or` as only one of them needs to evaluate to `true`: `if((A) || (!B && C))`